# Verification and Wording

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I just need to know if my thinking is correct aka I'm doing it correctly: sometimes the wording trips me up and I second guess myself. The following is the question/summary of it:

It's about the length of State of the Union Addresses, etc. They say *the mean length for these addresses is 51.75 minutes and the standard deviation is 14.37 minutes. Assume the length of a State of the Union Address is **normally distributed**.*

Now does normally distributed mean anything? Or can I just standardize whatever they ask about? For example:

*What is the probability that the next State of the Union Address will be between 45 and 55 minutes long?* What I did for this was standardized this then use the standard normal distribution cumulative probabilities table (which this question comes from the section in my book: full title of my section - Continuous Probability Distributions: The Normal Distribution).

Or do I do something else?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are told that the length of the address is normally distributed, that $X \sim Normal(\mu = 51.75, \sigma = 14.37)$. From this you can conclude that if the next address is randomly selected, the probability will follow $X$ and since $X$ is some normally distributed random variable, you can standardize this to $Z \sim Normal(\mu = 0, \sigma^2 = 1)$ and calculate the probability.